# Contact form needs to send email to content of email field - using Freeform Next v3

Tags: solspace-freeform, ee7

I need a contact form users can use to send an inquiry to an email provided with a list of multiple events. The email address is not visible to the public, but is provided with the channel entry for each event. The field for this address is {contact_email}.

I built a form that successfully sends a copy of the email notification to our office email (Admin Recipients), but not to the intended primary recipients.

Here is the opening to the form:

> {exp:freeform_next:form
> form_name="contact_acim_group_host"
> required="firstname|lastname|email|email_confirm"
> matching_fields="email|email_confirm"
> return="http://www.pathwaysoflight.org/acim_groups/thank_you"
> recipients="{contact_email}"
> admin_notify="info@pathwaysoflight.org"
> user_notification_template="group_info_request"
> user_notify="{contact_email}"
> template="contact_acim_group_host"
> }

The template contains the following fields: 1st name; last name; comments (text area).

The subject of the notification email is set with this line:

> <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" value="Request for information about your ACIM study group."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a notification for this. In the notification recipient field enter the email field with curly braces that you want to use, e.g. `{contact_email}`

Comment: I tried this, but it did not send an email to the recipient. Perhaps it is because the 'contact_email' field is within an EE Grid field.

Here is what I entered:

recipients="yes"
recipients="{contact_email}"
recipient_notification_template="group_info_request"
recipient_notify="{contact_email}"